# Photoshop not exporting shapes

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, shapes

[image]

Why isn't the lines exporting in the pdf file?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem too. It's a visual mistake in the PDF viewer. If the line is too thin it doesn't show it on the PDF.

If you make the line thicker it should show up in the PDF.